# Should search and sort filters be reset?

Tags: user-interface

I have a database app where records can be added, sorted and searched. When I add a record should the sort and search filter be reset or should they be kept and only the records that meet the requirements of the filter will be displayed?

I'm thinking of resetting, but im not sure